# Transition not working on text-fill-color

Tags: html, css

Transition not working on text-fill-color and I cannot figure out the issue here.

```css
.project {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #000;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #000;
  transition: all ease-in 3s;
}

.project:hover {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-container">
  <div class="project">
    Transition Not Working
  </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: It's working just fine, try decreasing the `transition-duration` and increase the font size for better output.

Comment: @James hey thanks for your comment. I just ran this on Safari and it seems working well. However, on my Chrome browser, it is not working. Do you know why?

Comment: I works in Chrome but the text-stroke makes it look like it's not.

Comment: Nah it doesn't work in my Chrome.. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1):

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color):

> Non-standard: This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

I replaced `-webkit-text-fill-color` with `color`, and it seems to work just fine

```css
.project {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 48px;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #000;
  transition: all ease-in 0.3s;
}

.project:hover {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-container">
  <div class="project">
    Transition Not Working
  </div>
<div>
```